# Google Places Api Android

Tags: android, google-play, google-places-api

I am searching for something where, I needs to pass my current location details(latitude and longitude) and retrieve the type of current place.

For example, If I am standing at ATM, and If I pass the latitude and longitude, Google should return me something like **ATM** as type.

For this purpose, I am using [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/current-place)

```
PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
.getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
@Override
public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
  Log.i(TAG, String.format("Place '%s' has likelihood: %g",
      placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
      placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));
}
likelyPlaces.release();
}
});
```

This is the main focus of code.

But Here It returns list of places Instead of one.
I supposed that, Inside **getCurrentPlace** function of **PlaceDetectionApi** I should pass the radius instead of null. But I am not getting how to pass it.
 And my GoogleApiClient object is

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .build();
```

Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: put code of mGoogleApiClient

Comment: Doesn't the Places API only provide information for known addresses? Like, it will tell you if you're at a Bank and additionally return all nearby places, but there's no way to known the "type" of place like ATM. For example, if you're in a mall, it might say the name of the mall, not the store you're in

Comment: The getCurrentPlace method returns a list of places because the Places API cannot be certain which one the user is currently at. That is why there is a "likelihood" associated with each place. That likelihood is an indication of how confident the Places API is that you are actually at that particular place. The first place in the list will be the most likely. If you only want to consider one place, just look at the first place in the list.

Answer (score 1):

To get Atm List , Here is Google official [link](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/?csw=1) to get atm list of nearer location

Click on Place type Google will give you input parameter for place type, there you have to pass following parameter from the list . to know list of parameter click on this [link](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I mentioned ATM as example only,
I don't know the current place type of the user. Once passing the latitude and longitude, It should return the type

Comment: @JayVyas Please check this sample you will got your answer http://karnshah8890.blogspot.in/2013/03/google-places-api-tutorial.html

Comment: @JayVyas if you have got your answer then please accept answer so other also can also get help from it

Answer (score 1):

> Google should return me place type. visit [getPlacesTypes()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place#public-methods)

```
List<Integer> types = placeLikelihood.getPlace().getPlaceTypes();
```

> But Here It returns list of places Instead of one

That is obvious that same location can be related to other places also. Check @cricket_007 comment.

Comment: excuse me, im working with this but types return this kind of numbers [69, 1013, 34]  for a place, but instead of it i would like it to say like , restaurant, hotel, bar, cafe, airport , just that, is there a way to get this data instead of the whole direction?

Comment: @GastónSaillén check constants of Place interface, for your response its  [TYPE_PARK, TYPE_POINT_OF_INTEREST, TYPE_ESTABLISHMENT]